# How to rewrite this rails 4 query to reduce the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails query where I am selecting all trial ids where the names field is blank or nil.  Is there a way to rewrite this so it's cleaner?

```
Trial.where(names: "").pluck(:id) + Trial.where(names: nil).pluck(:id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way I know how to write it is:

```
Trial.where(name: [nil, '']).ids
```

This will find all `Trial` record IDs where `name` is NULL or blank. Tt produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT `trials`.`id` FROM `trials`  WHERE ((`trials`.`name` = '' OR `trials`.`name` IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Trial.where("names = '' or names is null").pluck :id
```

**Edit**

There is a even cleaner option. Create a scope like this:

**Trial Model:**

```
class Trial < ActiveRecord::Base 
    scope :ids_with_blank_names, where("names = '' or names is null").pluck :id
end
```

Then in you controller you can use simply `Trial.ids_with_blank_names`